# Making unique stats for different classes

Tags: java, inheritance, subclassing

What I'm trying to do is I have one class called "Unit" which describes the general statistics of a unit in the Warhammer TableTop game and a subclass that has the more specific stats initialized for that class and then trying to see if I can successfully program an attack phase(?).

```
public class Unit {

    protected int bravery;
    protected int wounds;
    protected int movementInInches;
    protected int save;

    protected int range;
    protected int attacks;
    protected int successfulHit;
    protected int successfulWound;
    protected int rend;
    protected int damageDealt;

    protected int unitSize;

    public Unit(int n) {
        n = unitSize;
    }

    public void attack(Unit a, Unit b) {

    }
}


public class Greatswords extends Unit {

    public int bravery = 6;
    public int wounds= 1;
    public int movementInInches = 5;
    public int save = 4;

    public int range = 1;
    public int attacks = 2;
    public int successfulHit = 4;
    public int successfulWound = 3;
    public int rend = 1;
    public int damageDealt = 1;

    public Greatswords(int n) {
        super(n);
    }
}


public class BlackOrcs extends Unit {

    public int bravery = 6;
    public int wounds = 2;
    public int movementInInches = 4;
    public int save = 4;

    public int range = 1;
    public int attacks = 2;
    public int successfulHit = 4;
    public int successfulWound = 3;
    public int rend = 1;
    public int damageDealt = 1;

    public BlackOrcs(int n) {
        super(n);
    }
}
```

Obviously, I have not made the attack phase yet, and I kind of want to work on that on my own as I'm just treating this as practice. What I'm wondering is if hardcoding the example units like this is "correct" or if there is a correct way of doing this.

Comment: Note that your subclasses are hiding the variables in the base class - that's probably not your intention.

Comment: Your saying that the variables in the &quot;Unit&quot; class are useless with this configuration. Correct?

Comment: not understand why you are using inheritance, your subclass has different value not different behavior, it looks like you create the subclass instead  use a contractor, for different units you can use Enum as a type(if you wanna to save it) Unless you go to create Different methods and different properties between objects(not just diffrent values)

Comment: I'll look into it, I don't know what a contractor is though.

Comment: From what I'm looking at, it doesn't seem like Contracting is a thing. However, the reason why I'm using a subclass is that each unit has those types of statics but they vary from unit to unit. I'm planning on making it so that later on I can use excel for these statistics but baby steps first.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: I think @SarelFoyerlicht meant constructor instead of contractor.

Comment: After looking at the document on the link I posted, I realized what he meant. Thank you though.